# Moving a tag to the top of a todo bar

Tags: css

[image]

The spent text with the teal background is meant to be a tag, and I want the tag to appear above the todo bar...kind of like this:

[image]

Like a small rectangle on top of a big one. So the tag would be on the top left corner of the todo bar. How would I achieve this? I've tried doing margin to the tag, but that did not work out at all.

**CSS for the tag (style.css)**

```
.tag {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  background: #36d1dc;
  padding: 3px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

**React JS code for the tag part (Todo.js)**

```
<li className={`todo-item${todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}`}>
  {isSpent && <p className="tag">Spent</p>}
  {isReceived && <p className="tag">Received</p>} ${text}
</li>
```

In case anyone needs the whole of the `todo.css` file: https://pastecode.io/s/s5XZ9e3DRW

If you need anymore information, or if my question was poorly phrased, please tell me. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please post your html structure also, just for this part.

Comment: Hi...I still have this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if yow will separate the tag and the navbar to two different div tags and put them on main div something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top-left">top left div</div>
    <div id="down">down side div</div>
</div>
```

and the css will be something like (using grid on the main div):

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
}

#top-left {
  background: green;
  width: 250px;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#down {
  background: blue;
  float:left;
  width: 500px;
}
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: [CSS Code](https://pastecode.io/s/Rh9W8yDDy3), [React JS Code](https://pastecode.io/s/zSQnu03TuS), [Result](https://ibb.co/XkHqwbm). What did I do wrong? The only things I didn't include were the background for `#top-left` and width in `#top-left` Thank you Kfir!

Comment: I think the technique here is to use the display grid on the wrapper and define the sizes of the two div tag, did you try that? (also define float as left)

Comment: I added the width in for `#top-left` and I have already defined float as left in `#top-left` and `#down`. When I added the width for `#top-left` all I got was a wider tag. [Code](https://pastecode.io/s/a9LzGArgnb)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this, where `input:focus` could be a class set on on `.container`, for example, if the input has any values.

I couldn't understand why you used `li` and `p` in your original code, because you need to override so much stuff to make it look nice.

Using "rem" over a fixed pixel value is also preferred if you want to create a responsive site, where you just override the font-size in the `body` to make everything scale.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

body,
input {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container.selected > .todo-item,
input:focus ~ .todo-item {
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
}

.todo-item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(1rem);
  
  transition: transform 400ms;
}

.tag {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  background: #36d1dc;
  padding: 3px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="number">
  <div class="todo-item"><span class="tag">Spent</span></div>
  <div style="padding-top: 1rem"><-- select this input</div>
</div>

<div class="selected container" style="padding-top: 2rem">
  <input type="number">
  <div class="todo-item"><span class="tag">Spent</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rickard, thank you for your answer. To make things clear (unless everyone already knows), the white bar with the three buttons on the right, which is what I call a todo bar, it is **not** an input. Even though this is really cool and fancy, it's not really what I intended. But I'll try just taking away the animation. Thank you again Rickard!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #48AEE0;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.tag {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #36d1dc;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.other {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="tag">spent</div>
        <div class="others">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Part of Todo.js](https://pastecode.io/s/7S2KVGPBut), [Part of todo.css](https://pastecode.io/s/r3P39QE85H), [Result](https://ibb.co/TR7gfdp). I have no idea what is going on...and also the todo bar is not an input. I also commented out the height and width for the `bar-tag-container` because all it did was just make the todo bar bigger.